# XML deserialization is extremely slow - Apache Axis 1.4

Tags: java, xml, deserialization, axis, xml-deserialization

I have intermitten issue after invoking web service thru Axis, deserialization of xml is really slow.
Response of xml is small < 5kb.

Below screenshot of elapses times for all methods during deserialization.

[image]

I'm using JDK 1.7, Axis 1.4 and Xerces 2.11.0. Can someone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem, it's due to keep-alive in HTTP response header. Apparently you have to change default http client in axis to use CommonsHTTPSender instead of HTTPSender.

The issue is reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-636